# Visual Studio 2010 linker [C]

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2831379/1945967), that the best way to place functions is to create .h file with function prototypes, some .c file with those functions (including their bodies) and normal .c file with main().
This is how my simple project looks:
[image: Project]
it works properly, but how Visual Studio knows how to link them properly? In GCC I can control the order while linking.

Comment: Visual Studio will just compile all source files in the `Source Files` folder to object files and then link them together automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to control the order - the compiler does that.  If the files are in the project, the linker will do its job.