# How to create my own header file in c++?

Tags: c

I m a new budding programmer.Is it possible for me to create a new header file of my own? Can anyone help me how to create my own header file in c++ with an example ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create C header files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831361/how-can-i-create-c-header-files)

Comment: See this webpage: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, of course you can, but before that you need to learn what header files are and how you can use them properly.

file: yourname.h

```
#ifndef YOUR_NAME_INCLUDE
#define YOUR_NAME_INCLUDE

/* Your function statement here */
#endif
```

yourname.cpp

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include "yourname.h"

/* Your function definition here */
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include "yourname.h"

/* Your function calling here */
```

To learn more about header files and include statements, click the link below.

> [Header tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/)

Comment: this is missing `#endif` in *.h

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create your own header file.

1. Kindly go through thinking in c++ by bruce eckel vol 1.
2. Just to begin with, a header file is which has extension '.h'/'.hpp'
3. These files have declaration of user defined data structures and interfaces such has class declaration, function prototypes and etc.
4. After declaring and storing it into project folder. you need to include this file in .cpp/.c
   eg.:

file: myheader.h

```
#ifndef MYHEADER 
#define MYHEADER
    ......
#endif
```

file: myclass.cpp

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include "myheader.h"
```

Comment: is it necessary to write in capital: **MYHEADER** when the file named `myheader.h`?