# cannot open the header file in C++

Tags: c++

I'm doing my assignment that need to using the #include function
but I found that after I define the header file, I cannot open the header file in the main.cpp
and I also didn't find any xxx.h file in the project file

here is the situation

[image]

[image]

[image]

The reason of search.h can open is I found that in external dependencies file, there is a search.h, but the search.h I want to open is not the search.h in external dependencies file

Comment: clearly you need those files so your program can work, maybe ask the professor who gives you the assignment would help

Comment: Did you create the project from scratch or did somebody gave you that project folder and you opened it in VS?

Comment: The professor only give us a cpp file of the whole program and need us to separate it, so I already cut the file into 6 pieces

Comment: That means you're expected to split out the header file yourself and add it to the project. What exactly it is going to contain, is up to you to solve, as a part of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have header files in your project. [Create the header files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20015801/5986104) `xxx.h` in the project directory. So the compiler will be able to locate them.

If the person who gave you the project has provided you the header files along with the project requirements then, just copy and paste the `xxx.h` files into the project directory. This would solve your problem.

To learn more about the header file. Click on the below tutorial link

> [Header Files](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/)
>
> [How to add header files in Visual Studio 2010 - Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKiZU4RmZW8)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have any header files included in your project. Visual Studio is attempting to find the header files in the header directory of your project but it cannot find any. Save your header files into separate files and add them to your header directory in the project. Then you should not have any problem.