# How do I make header files?

Tags: c++

I have gotten to a point in my course where they use Code::Blocks to automatically make a header file.  However, I don't think it's necessary to download Code::Blocks specifically for this reason, and so I am looking for a way to make my own header files.

And so, I started my search online to find out exactly how to do this.
I checked [How to create my own header file in c++? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015656/how-to-create-my-own-header-file-in-c) and also [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/#msg49679)

However, the former uses uses `#ifndef YOUR_NAME_INCLUDE` and `#define YOUR_NAME_INCLUDE` whereas the latter uses `#ifndef __X_H_INCLUDED__` and `#define __X_H_INCLUDED__`, with 2 underscores surrounding the `#ifndef` and `#define`.  How should I format my header guards?  Does it really matter?

For example, if I have a file `foo.h`, which looks like this:

```
#ifndef ???
#define ???

int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

#endif
```

should I put `SUM_INCLUDED`, `FOO_INCLUDED`, `FOO_H` instead of the `???` or something else altogether?

Second, is making a header file really as easy as just sticking a `.h` or `.hpp` to the end of it?

Comment: This is a good question, but I'm not sure if it fits the StackOverflow model that well. Regardless, yes, header files are just any file which is `#include`d in another file, so it could be a `.h`, a `.hpp`, a `.hxx`, a `.h++`, a `.hh`, a `.helloworld` or whatever you like. I personally use `.hpp` (I don't like `.h`, because `.hpp` gives my editor a hint that the file is for C++ rather than C). Then, for the header guards (the `#ifndef` + `#define` part), it's just whatever you want to do. I would personally recommend `FOO_H` or `FOO_INCLUDED`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what exactly you write here, as long as each header has a unique string. Though the standard says that names containing `__` are reserved, so you shouldn't use it. You're also missing `#endif` at the end of file.

Comment: Oh my lord the first plain english explain-like-I'm-five answer I've seen all day!  Thank you @Justin

Comment: @HolyBlackCat oops.  Lemme fix that.

Comment: Aside from the "header guards" discussed above, the "How do I write a header?" approach is you generally code until your source file becomes to big to comfortably scroll through. Then you look for like/related functions to move to a separate source file to reduce the size of the current file. To include the functions you move back in the current file, you create a header that normally contains the function prototypes for each moved function, along with any constants or structs you need to expose. Wrap that info in the header-guards and you have a header for the moved functions.

Comment: If you put the function body inside the .h file as you've done here, then the function should be marked `inline`, otherwise you'll get linker errors if you include this in more than one file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create my own header file in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015656/how-to-create-my-own-header-file-in-c)

Comment: @TruVortex_07 probably the biggest reason I asked this question is because that question itself caused confusion for me, as the accepted answer doesn't use underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 #ifndef FOO
 #define FOO

 struct foo {};

 #endif
```

The above canonical example ensures that the contents (between `#ifndef FOO` and `#define FOO`) are compiled only once allowing us to include this file (say `foo.h`) in multiple compilation units without causing `struct foo` to be multiply defined.

There really isn't any "magic" about an include file other than this.  In fact, the extension doesn't even matter.  It could be `foo.h` or `foo.hh` or just `foo` (like the standard library headers like `vector` or `iostream`).

Ultimately, it's personal preference how you structure your include guards.  Some use `__FOO__` (note this runs afoul of C++ standard regarding reserved identifiers) or `FOO_H_INCLUDED` (which is standard compliant) while others may elect for different patterns.

While it's not strictly standard C++, my team uses `#pragma once` and foregoes the ifndef/define/endif code.  It's supported by all the compilers we use (gcc/msvc/clang) and you don't have drawbacks such as too different `foo.h` files causing one (or the other) definition to be excluded.

The same file then looks like this

```
#pragma once
struct foo {};
```

Comment: "Ultimately, it's personal preference how you structure your include guards."  This is misleading, since the C++ standard reserves a (large) set of identifiers for use by the implementation,  and ANY code that uses reserved identifier has undefined behaviour.   "Some use `__FOO__` others may elect for different patterns."  Anyone who does this introduced undefined behaviour, since *all* identifiers that begin with an underscore that is followed by either a second underscore or an uppercase letter are reserved.

Comment: Yeah, edited to include that detail though many editors follow this non-compliant pattern by default