# Calling Obj-C method from C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I've got a library written in C, where I need to push a call to a method written in Obj-c.
I don't want to modify the original code too much, so I decided to create a "bridge" class to handle the calls between C and ObjC:

`DRMBridge.h`

```
#ifndef DRMBridge_h
#define DRMBridge_h

#include "DRMBridgeObjC.h"

void bridge_test();


#endif
```

`DRMBridge.c`

```
#import "DRMBridge.h"


void bridge_test() {

    ctest();

 }
```

Above is compiled as C

Now here's my objc code:

`DRMBridgeObjC.h`

```
#ifndef DRMBridgeObjC_h
#define DRMBridgeObjC_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface DRMBridgeObjC : NSObject

+(void) test;

@end

void ctest();

#endif
```

`DRMBridgeObjC.m`

```
#import "DRMBridgeObjC.h"

@implementation DRMBridgeObjC : NSObject 

+(void) test  {
    NSLog(@"OH YEAH!");
}
@end


void ctest() {
    [DRMBridgeObjC test];
}
```

Quite simple.

In the C library I want to call my code from I've added:
`#include "DRMBridge.h"`
into the .h file and 
`bridge_test();`
in .c file.

Now the best part, when I compile I get:

```
In file included from /Users/krystian/projects/mdb-reader-lib/reader-Include/ios/MDBReader/Class/DRM/DRMBridge.c:5:
In file included from /Users/krystian/projects/mdb-reader-lib/reader-Include/ios/MDBReader/Class/DRM/DRMBridge.h:8:
In file included from /Users/krystian/projects/mdb-reader-lib/reader-Include/ios/MDBReader/Class/DRM/DRMBridgeObjC.h:12:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode64.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode64.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:400:1: error: expected identifier or '('
@class NSString, Protocol;
^
[...]
```

I went looking, and found this: [ios - Parse Issues in NSObjCRuntime, NSZone, and NSObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857765/ios-parse-issues-in-nsobjcruntime-nszone-and-nsobject)

However my `pch` file looks like this:

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

I think the issue I have is that the C compiler tries to compile my ObjC file first, instead of the other way around.
I've tried changing the order of files inside `Compile Sources` to make sure that my `.m` file is above `.c` file, but still no go.

Something else I have found which made me lost:

when I follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461780/487605 and change the library itself to `.m`, and call `[DRMBridgeObjC test]` code from there - it works.... Compiles fine, no errors given, works fine.

This implies to me, that there's something screwed up with my `DRMBridge`, but what?

Thanks
Krystian

Answer (score 1):

You've seen the solution already. Use #ifdef __ OBJC__ in your Objective-C header file so that only the plain C bits are compiled when including the file from C

Comment: your solution works, but I'm wondering why I didn't have to go through that when I made change to the C code from the library? There was no need.

Comment: Maybe the library did the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

DRMBridge.h

```
#ifndef DRMBridge_h
#define DRMBridge_h

#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h> //or put in .pch

CF_EXPORT void bridge_test();

#endif
```

DRMBridge.m

```
#import "DRMBridge.h"
#import "DRMBridgeObjC.h"


void bridge_test() {

    ctest(); //or [DRMBridgeObjC test]; if you like

 }
```

Thats all. And you can include DRMBridge.h in whatever you like: in .c, in .m, in .cpp.

Comment: It sounds great, but I get `Unknown type CF_ECTERN` :/ Is there something special I should do?

Comment: I'm using XCode 6.4 if that matters.

Comment: @Krystian, oh `CF_EXPORT` not `CF_EXTERN`.

Comment: thanks, I've changed `CF_EXPORT` into `CF_EXTERN`, however still the same issue. When I add `#import "DRMBridgeObjC.h"` into the `DRMBridge.h` file, the `CF_EXPORT` is accepted, however I'm back to the `NSObjCRuntime.h` errors as described in the question.

Comment: Ok, you will need include `CoreFoundation.h` and don't put `DRBridgeObjC.h` in `DRMBridge.h`

Comment: @Krystian, Btw. you can trow `CF_EXPORT` away if you not going include `DRMBridge.h` in .cpp.