# header.h: No such file or directory even though source and header are in same directory

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, header

I have made a header and a source but I don't know how to link them up. I looked it up on the web but the commands provided didn't work (or I wouldn't be here :) ).

To compile it (if you use GCC):

Header:

```
$ gcc -c whatever.h -o whatever.o
```

Source:

```
$ gcc -c sample.c -o sample.o
```

To link the files to create an executable file:

```
$ gcc sample.o whatever.o -o sample
```

What did I do wrong. I am using geany for writing (compile error is here) but the commands are executed on a terminal in the same directory. can anybody give me the build commands for geany so whenever I want to include a header I can just compile and run?

Comment: Why don't you use `#include "header.h"` in `sample.c`?

Comment: Then why you're compiling and linking it? :-)

Comment: @CoderGuy You're not supposed to compile headers in the first place.

Comment: @biffen i got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831361/how-can-i-create-c-header-files

Comment: @CoderGuy And which part of that told you to compile a header file?

Comment: @biffen where the commands are? idk i just followed that

Comment: @CoderGuy You mean where it says `gcc -c whatever.c -o whatever.o`? Note that `whatever.c` != `whatever.h`.

Comment: yes the gcc stands for compiling right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good and the right way would be to

**sample.c**

```
#include "header.h"
```

and compile

```
gcc sample.c -o ob
```

Comment: How would that be in geany (Build and compile commands). that would be easyer

Comment: what does the f2.c and f1.c stand for? in geany build commands it's all like "%f" and stuff

Comment: @CoderGuy Let me not confuse you please include the header in .c file compile and run..

Comment: but the header is a .h file

Comment: I did, it says that the file is not found but it is in the same directory as the c file

Comment: @CoderGuy *How*, *exactly*, do you include it?

Comment: @CoderGuy Show your .c and .h file and how you are including the header.. Nothing to do with geany.

Comment: @CoderGuy I compiled built and ran in geany .. I don't get your problem

Comment: i use `#include <header.h>`

Comment: @CoderGuy There you go!! Please use `#include "header.h"` .. Use double quotes instead of  `<` `>` brackets

Comment: @CoderGuy Is your header called `header.h` or `whatever.h`?

Comment: well, non of the above, but it contains my full name so I don't want to type it here. anyway you can use whatever you want for your example, I'll probably understand

Comment: @CoderGuy You need to understand the difference between `#include<header.h>` and `#include "header.h"`  Is your issue resolved or not? Hold on... your need to include `#include "yourfullname.h"` Whatever your full name is ....

Comment: so not with the `<>` thing

Comment: @CoderGuy NO !! with `" "`

Answer (score 4):

Thumb Rule:

- header files [`.h`] are for `#include`ing
- source files [`.c`] are for compiling and linking together to create the executable.

Once you've `#include`d your header file in a `.c` file, there's no need to compile the header file and produce an object file.

FYI, you can check the effect of `#include`-ing the header file by running

```
gcc -E sample.c
```

and hope you'll understand why you *need not* compile and link the header file separately.

---

EDIT:

if you have a `sample.c` and `whatever.h`, to produce and run the binary, simply do

- `#include "whatever.h"` in the top of `sample.c`
- `gcc -o sample sample.c`
- `./sample`

Comment: @CoderGuy Sorry, no. But how that is related to this?

Comment: @CoderGuy Your issue has nothing to do with the `geany` or anything. Kindly correct the actions, it'll work. :-)

Comment: @Biffen Whoops !! Typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you include header file by:

```
#include <header.h>
```

it will give this error.

Instead you can write as given below:

```
#include "header.h"
```