# [C++]function template with static keyword

Tags: c++, templates

code from google's v8 js engine, allocation.h:

```
 template <typename T>
 static void DeleteArray(T* array) {
  delete[] array;
}
```

This is a function template (top level, not in any class).
But what the static keyword is for?

Comment: It does the same thing as normal, non-templated `static` functions in headers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780730/c-c-static-function-in-header-file-what-does-it-mean

Comment: Since its almost certain to become an inlined function I'd say 'not alot' ;)

Comment: static in this context has been deprecated in favor of an anonymous namespace.

Comment: Personally I regard that as an error (because it is in the header file). It should probably by marked `inline` rather than `static`. In this context inline lets the compiler know that there mya be multiple versions of a function in different compilation units and thus it should pick one at link time (if some have not actually been physically inlined).

Comment: @Martin: In case of templates, `inline` should not be needed. Templates are always implicitly inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `static` keyword gives the definition "internal linkage", which means it would be legal to give the name `DeleteArray` another meaning or a different definition in a different source file.  (Just as is the case with `static void f();` or `static int i;`.)  But I can't imagine anyone would want to do that.

Use of `static` this way in C++ is deprecated.  This declaration would probably be better without the `static` keyword, making it implicitly `extern` (and still `inline`).  In that case, the linker would be allowed to combine any definitions of `DeleteArray<T>(T*)` for the same `T` from multiple objects, since they would be the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

That it's a template is actually a side-issue.

It being static means the function is not visible outside of the file (but since it's in a header and headers are effectively part of the files that include them, that means outside of the file that includes the header; and each file that includes the header effectively has its own, identical but private version of the function).

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd%28VS.80%29.aspx:

> "When modifying a variable or function
>   at file scope, the static keyword
>   specifies that the variable or
>   function has internal linkage (its
>   name is not visible from outside the
>   file in which it is declared)."

See here fore more on what it means to have this in a header file:

[C/C++: Static function in header file, what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780730/c-c-static-function-in-header-file-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: private as in the compilation unit will not expose the symbol name for the linker to resolve dependencies with.

Answer (score 0):

`static` functions (outside of a class) cannot be used [outside the defining file](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/SYNTAX/static.htm). It's a holdover from C where there are no namespaces. I bet you'll find that `DeleteArray()` isn't called from another file, unless it's been redefined in that other file.