# static inline free function

Tags: c++, function, static, free, inline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++: Static function in header file, what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780730/c-c-static-function-in-header-file-what-does-it-mean)

I have found a function in code that I am working with:

in msgparser.hpp

```
static inline msgEnum msg2enum(char *str)
{
    msgEnum enumValue;

    ....

    return enumValue;
}
```

The function parses the string and determines which enum it matches with from a pre-defined array of message strings.

It is a free function.

I know what `inline` means - a hint to the compiler that the function should be inlined.

My questions are:

What does `static` mean for a free function in a header?

Can it be meaningfully combined with `inline`?

Comment: @sharptooth, perhaps a special case worthy of new answers since the `static` is not needed when the function is marked `inline`.

Comment: Isn't there a notable difference between C and C++ here? I find no mention of free static functions in C++0x FDIS, only with regard to variables and member functions?

Comment: @rubenvb: They behave the same in C and C++ prior to C++0x.

Comment: To answer the part of this question that the "duplicate" doesn't: `inline` won't have its usual effect on a `static` function, since its purpose is to allow functions with *external linkage* to be defined in multiple compilation units; the `static` function has *internal linkage*, so can already be multiply defined. It may still act as a "hint" to inline function calls, if the compiler pays any attention to that. In a header, you're better off marking the function just `inline`, so that you should only end up with a single version of it.

Comment: If the user compiles with optimization off (`-O0` usually), then `inline` gets ignored and functions defined in headers get multiply instantiated (read: link fails), *unless* they are also marked `static`. This is not an unusual case: Sometimes, when hunting a difficult bug with a source-level debugger, you'll want inlining (and other optimizations) turned off to keep from breaking the single-step debug function.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone: regardless of optimisation, you're allowed multiple (identical) definitions of `inline` functions with external linkage; they don't need to be (and usually shouldn't be) declared `static`. It's up to the linker to identify `inline` function definitions, and discard duplicates without error.

Comment: OK, the linker wasn't that smart back when this last bit me in '02.